# Null Reference exception converting string from config file to int

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

NOTE: This question was marked as a duplicate of a post about null reference exceptions. This is not a duplicate. That post is general information about null reference exceptions and this post is about the fact that I can't convert a string to integer if the string comes from an appsettings config file.

This is in .NET Core 8.0. I read a string value from an `appsettings.json` config file. When I try to convert the string to an  int, I get a null reference exception.

I have tried using `Int32.Parse`, `Int32.TryParse`, `Convert.ToInt32`. I tried converting the value to UTF8.

All return the same error. See the screenshot for the `TryParse` attempt. The string variable has the value. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

edit -
Here is the config section:

```
 {

"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "System": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
},
"Console": {
  "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Warning"
  }
},
"DaysToDelete": "30",
"BasePath": "D:\\WebServices\\SalesForceFiles\\"

}
```

The code is below. In the original I use the same syntax for getting "BasePath" as I do for "DaysToDelete".

```
 var basePath = _config.GetSection("BasePath").Value;
 var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(basePath);

//I tried Steve Wong's suggestion. Same error
string? daysToDeleteString = _config.GetValue<string>("DaysToDelete"); 

byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(daysToDeleteString);
string deleteDays = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

//this line throws the error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object
var del = Int32.TryParse(deleteDays, out int result);
```

The variable for deleteDays has the value "30", it is not null. I showed the screenshot to show that the variable is not null.

Comment: `DaysToDelete` does not appear to be a section.  Have you tried `_config.GetValue<string>("DaysToDelete")`?

Comment: Please add your code and the exception as text. Don't use screenshots unless there's something that you need to show that cannot be provided as text.

Comment: From the screenshot, you appear to be ignoring a null-state analysis warning, so it's no wonder you're getting a `NullReferenceException`. Deal with the warning, first. It's there for a reason.

Comment: Post the config file that is suppose to contain "DaysToDelete".

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem. https://dotnetfiddle.net/NRcA8I Please read through making a [mre]. As Steve said, "GetSection" probably isn't an appropriate API to use.

Comment: @gunr2171 The other values work fine using "GetSection." And daysToDelete has its value using this syntax too. ANd I tried Steve Wong's way of using "GetValue"> I get the same error on the same line of code. And yes, daysToDelete has a value of "30" with a string length of 2.